# measuring resistances of CT

Tags: current-measurement, current-transformer

Mayby, Sorry for a basic question.

When measuring CT working okay in maintenance, somebody say that the resistance of 0 & (+Vc) and 0 & (-Vc) should have similar values.

Buu, I wonder why these two resistance should be similar to. Also, though using multimeter is simple, is there any other way to check it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Not sure what your question is. Is it about primary and secondary resistance? Or the differential driver outputs +Vc and -Vc? Please be more specific and add details to your questions.

Comment: @heesung: Please use capital letters at the start of title and sentences. If you don't it affects legibility and gives an unfavourable impression of the author.

Comment: Thanks you for your advice. Forgive my lack of experience of using these.

Answer (score 1):

> When measuring CT working okay in maintenance, somebody say that the resistance of 0 & (+Vc) and 0 & (-Vc) should have similar values.
>   I wonder why these two resistance should be similar to.

Tell 'somebody' that this is not true with active electronics. The circuits are complex arrangements of integrated and discrete components and when they include transistors and diodes a simple resistance check will tell you very little.

> Also, though using multimeter is simple, is there any other way to check it?

Power it up. Feed it a test current. Measure the output voltage. In your case the device is high current (500 A) so you could pass multiple turns through it to simulate a high current. e.g., Use a 10 A heater as a test load, wind 10 turns through the sensor and it should read 100 A.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As fas as I know, I agree with you that it is not that simple to check with just a multimeter.